# Have Rails specify protocol for specific request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My production server uses HTTPS. I'm unable to return data from a request to an API which uses HTTP (e.g. RestClient.get("http://")).

How can I set the protocol (http://) for a specific request?

I have seen a solution using redirect_to in controllers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559432).
I'm looking for a solution which can be used for a specific request in any class.

Comment: RestClient should be able to work with both http/https services. Are you sure it's not a firewall that is blocking outbound http calls?

Comment: The outbound http call works in development(http), but not in production(https). In production I can return data from RestClient.get("https://") but not RestClient.get("http://").

Comment: By `production`, I'm assuming you mean a production server and not running locally using the rails production environment. If that is the case, I think your problem is still with a firewall or some other network device that is not allowing you to make outbound HTTP calls. You can confirm this easily on both development and production servers by a simple curl command, e.g. `curl http://www.google.com`

Comment: Correct this is a heroku production server. `heroku run curl http://www.google.com` returns data. However `heroku run rails c` then `RestClient.get("http://")` does not.

Comment: Okay it seems to be specific to this API URL (other http request are returning data). Any suggestions on how to test these heroku network devices if that's the problem? p.s. I was instructed by an engineer of the API to disable https for that request - saying it wouldn't work with that request. I'm not sure why that would be.